# svn2git stop processing with error message "command failed"

Tags: svn2git

While using svn2git to transfer an svn project to git project, I encountered following problem.

command failed:
git checkout -b "1.7.8" "remotes/svn/1.7.8"

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is that there is an .gitattributes file in the svn repository and the content of that file is

```
text=auto
```

after add --exclude ".*gitattributes$" to the svn2git command, the problem is resolved.